# draw video to canvas across domains

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-canvas

I have a `video` tag linked to a movie at `content.mysite.com`, and I have a script file served from `www.mysite.com` (different subdomain).

The script creates a `canvas` element and captures the video to the canvas using `context.drawImage` method. But when I attempt to get the image data from the canvas using `canvas.toDataURL` method, it fails with a security error because of cross domain restrictions.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set CORS headers on video files:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control

According to this bug report it is supported on `<video>` since Firefox 12:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=682299

I think at least Chrome should support it, other browsers might not.

Comment: Relevant spec: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/fetching-resources.html#cors-settings-attribute